# Ionic 3 Tabs are not refreshed after initialized

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

Each tab calls the same Component "EventDetailItemsComponent" with different navParams. And the async data (Observable) is retrieved from this.itemService and displayed as expected.

Problem starts when I switch back to the same tab the second time. Since Component is not called again, it displays the same async data. So tab view is not updated.

What I want is to call EventDetailItemsComponent every time a tab is clicked. Not just on the first click.

Would it be the right way to pass that async data from parent component EventDetailComponent  to child component EventDetailItemsComponent with (ionSelect)="myMethod()"

```
    <ion-tabs no-margin no-padding selectedIndex="1">
        <ion-tab [root]="EventDetailItems1" [rootParams]="{itemTypeId:1, eventId: (eventDetail | async)?.id}" tabTitle="{{'ALL' | translate}}"></ion-tab>
        <ion-tab [root]="EventDetailItems2" [rootParams]="{itemTypeId:2, eventId: (eventDetail | async)?.id}" tabTitle="{{'BOUGHT' | translate}}"></ion-tab>
        <ion-tab [root]="EventDetailItems3" [rootParams]="{itemTypeId:3, eventId: (eventDetail | async)?.id}" tabTitle="{{'LEFT' | translate}}"></ion-tab>
    </ion-tabs>


    export class EventDetailComponent implements OnInit {

        EventDetailItems1: any = EventDetailItemsComponent;
        EventDetailItems2: any = EventDetailItemsComponent;
        EventDetailItems3: any = EventDetailItemsComponent;

        constructor(){ }
    }
```

Child Component EventDetailItemsComponent and its html

```
    @Component({
        selector: 'event-detail-items',
        styleUrls: ['/event-detail-items.scss'],
        templateUrl: 'event-detail-items.html'
    })
    export class EventDetailItemsComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges  {
        private _itemDetail = new BehaviorSubject<ItemViewModel[]>(null);
        itemDetail = this._itemDetail.asObservable();

        itemToggle: number = 0;
        lastImage: string = null;
        loading: Loading;

        constructor(
            public itemService: ItemService,
            public eventService: EventService,
            public navParams: NavParams,
            public navCtrl: NavController,
            public loadingCtrl: LoadingController,
            private app: App) {

        }

        ngOnInit() {
            let itemParams: GiftItemTabNavParams = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.navParams.data));                
            this.itemService.getItemList(itemParams.eventId, itemParams.itemTypeId).subscribe(x => {
                this._itemDetail.next(x);
            });
        }
    }


          <ion-grid id="gift-list-grid">                
            <ion-row class="gift-list-row" *ngFor="let giftItem of (itemDetail | async)" text-center bottom>
                <ion-col (click)="toggleItemDescription(giftItem.id)" class="gift-item-col-item-pic" col-3>
                    <img src="{{giftItem.giftImagePath}}" />
                </ion-col>
                <ion-col (click)="toggleItemDescription(giftItem.id)" class="gift-item-col-detail" col-6>
                    <ion-label text-wrap class="gift-item-text" no-margin text-left>
                        <span>
                            {{giftItem.giftItemName}}
                        </span>
                        <span>
                            {{giftItem.brand}}
                        </span>
                    </ion-label>
                </ion-col>
                <ion-col (click)="toggleItemDescription(giftItem.id)" class="gift-item-col-gift-count" col-3>
                    <img src="./assets/img/inner-pages/gift_box.png" />
                    <p>
                        {{giftItem.amount}}
                    </p>
                </ion-col>
                <ion-col (click)="toggleItemDescription(giftItem.id)" *ngIf="itemToggle == giftItem.id" col-9>
                    <ion-label text-wrap class="gift-item-description" no-margin text-left>
                        <span>
                            {{giftItem.amount}} {{'AMOUNT' | translate}}
                        </span>
                        <span>
                            {{giftItem.description}}
                        </span>
                    </ion-label>
                </ion-col>
                <ion-col (click)="toggleBuyStatus(giftItem.id, giftItem.isBought, giftItem.giftStatus)" *ngIf="itemToggle == giftItem.id" class="gift-item-col-detail"  col-3>
                    <!--RESERVABLE ITEM-->
                    <img *ngIf="giftItem.giftStatus == 0" src="./assets/img/inner-pages/free.png" />
                    <!--CAN BE UNRESERVED-->
                    <img *ngIf="giftItem.giftStatus == 1" src="./assets/img/inner-pages/unreservable.png" />
                    <!--CAN NOT BE UNRESERVED-->
                    <img *ngIf="giftItem.giftStatus == 2" src="./assets/img/inner-pages/not-unreservable.png" />
                </ion-col>
            </ion-row>
        </ion-grid>
```

UPDATE: As Sampath suggests, Events solved the problem. You can find the usage below:

Root **EventDetailComponent** - Event Publish:

```
public eventTabsChanged(itemTypeId) {
            let event = this._eventDetail.getValue();
            this.events.publish('tab:clicked', itemTypeId, event.id);
        }
```

Tab content **EventDetailItemsComponent** - Event Subscribe

```
    constructor(
            public itemService: ItemService,       
            public events: Events) {
            events.subscribe('tab:clicked', (itemTypeId, eventId) => {
                this.itemService.getItemList(eventId, itemTypeId).subscribe(x => {
                    this._itemDetail.next(x);
                });
            });
        }
```

Comment: Can you show the child component's `code` too? `html` and `ts`.

Comment: @Sampath I added child component and its html

Comment: ion- tab or ion-grid click u want to update ?

Comment: @rashidnk do you suggest to use a click and inside the function, passing the async data to child component by using @Input?

Comment: Can you show the `code` of interaction between parent and child? `html` code?

Comment: there is no interaction between them. I am developing it right now just to give a try. Since I thought, child component was going be called every time I click on the tab, I didnt build an interraction between parent and child components

Comment: But I unfortunately found out that I cannot pass data between child and parent components through <ion-tab [itemDetail]="itemDetail">. Is it somehow possible? It throws the following error: "Can't bind to 'itemDetail' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-tab'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need to know how to pass data between `parent` to `child`.So you can do it using `input` properties.

**Option 1:**

In your case :

```
<event-detail-items [itemDetail]="itemDetail"></event-detail-items>
```

Please see the [**offical doc here**](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction).

*child.ts*

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

import { Hero } from './hero';

@Component({
  selector: 'hero-child',
  template: `
    <h3>{{hero.name}} says:</h3>
    <p>I, {{hero.name}}, am at your service, {{masterName}}.</p>
  `
})
export class HeroChildComponent {
  @Input() hero: Hero;
  @Input('master') masterName: string;
}
```

*parent.ts*

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { HEROES } from './hero';

@Component({
  selector: 'hero-parent',
  template: `
    <h2>{{master}} controls {{heroes.length}} heroes</h2>
    <hero-child *ngFor="let hero of heroes"
      [hero]="hero"
      [master]="master">
    </hero-child>
  `
})
export class HeroParentComponent {
  heroes = HEROES;
  master = 'Master';
}
```

**Option 2:** Using [**Events**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/util/Events/)

Comment: when I try <ion-tab [itemDetail]="itemDetail"> It throws such an error: "Can't bind to 'itemDetail' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-tab'" So ion-tab not accepting input parameters I guess.

Comment: I will try now to pass async data using [rootParams]. But [rootParams] is the end of my knowledge, If it doesn't work I will be totally stuck :)

Comment: You cannot do that.Because `ion-tab` is not your `child` component no? You need to bind it to your child component as like this: `<event-detail-items [itemDetail]="itemDetail"></event-detail-items> `

Comment: I was considering ion-tab as my child component. Is there any equivalent method for passing data between root component and ion-tab component?

Comment: No, you're wrong.You cannot consider it like that.You have another method to pass data between components.That is `Events`.See this: http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/util/Events/

Comment: I have updated my question and write the right usage of it.

Comment: Yep, Great... :)